# Catch pandas df.to_json() exception

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, exception

I am trying to determine the reason why I get a failure when executing the pandas `DataFrame.to_json()` method. The DataFrame is valid, but it's very large (on the order of 1,000,000 records).

Here is my code, where `predictions` is my DataFrame:

```python
try:
    predictions.to_json(write_file, orient='records', lines=True)
except EOFError as eoferr:
    print(eoferr)
    sys.exit('\nUnable to write file (%s)! EOFError. Exiting...' % write_file)
except IOError as ioerr:
    print(ioerr)
    sys.exit('\nUnable to write file (%s)! Permissions problem Exiting...' % write_file)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit('\nUnable to write file (%s)! Unknown exception. Exiting...' % write_file)
```

Right now, I am getting the `Unknown exception. Exiting...` exception being raised. Thanks in advance!

Comment: May try iterating through the rows and calling to_json on each row?

Comment: Thanks @mobone -- I figured out a workaround and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a *solution*, but a **workaround**.

I *believe* this is a memory issue with `DataFrame.to_json()` -- the machine would hang attempting to transform a DataFrame of ~ 5M records x 1000 columns into a JSON file, and exit raising a general `Exception`.

The workaround is to use `DataFrame.to_dict()` and then use `json.dump()`:

```
import json

write_file = "/path/to/output.json"
holder_dictionary = predictions.to_dict(orient='records')

with open(write_file, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(holder_dictionary, outfile)
```

This works (so far) for any size DataFrame. In the meantime, I am going to file a bug/issue on the Pandas repo.